# Use regular expression to remove contents in brackets in python

Tags: python, regex, list, python-2.7

I have a `list`:

```
['14147618', '(100%)', '6137776', '(43%)', '5943229', '(42%)', '2066613', '(14%)', 'TOTAL']
```

also as as string `'14147618 (100%)   6137776 (43%)   5943229 (42%)   2066613 (14%)  TOTAL\n'`

Using regex, how do I return:

```
['14147618', '6137776, '5943229', 2066613']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need RegEx at all, you can simply filter out the data which has only digits in them, with this list comprehension

```
print [item for item in data if item.isdigit()]
# ['14147618', '6137776', '5943229', '2066613']
```

Or you can also use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) builtin function, like this

```
print filter(str.isdigit, data)
# ['14147618', '6137776', '5943229', '2066613']
```

**Edit:** If you have the entire data as a single string, you can split the data based on whitespace characters and then use the same logic

```
data = '14147618 (100%)   6137776 (43%)   5943229 (42%)   2066613 (14%)  TOTAL\n'
print [item for item in data.split() if item.isdigit()]
# ['14147618', '6137776', '5943229', '2066613']
print filter(str.isdigit, data.split())
# ['14147618', '6137776', '5943229', '2066613']
```

Comment: Could u tell me if a = `'14147618 (100%)   6137776 (43%)   5943229 (42%)   2066613 (14%)  TOTAL\n'`
How do I get `['14147618', '6137776, '5943229', 2066613']`?

Comment: @VeilEclipse You can use the same program with `a.split()`

Answer (score 2):

As @thefourtheye said, it's not necessary to use regex at all, but if you *really want* to do it with regex, you can use:

```
import re

a = ['14147618', '(100%)', '6137776', '(43%)', '5943229', '(42%)', '2066613', '(14%)', 'TOTAL']
result = []

for e in a:
    m = re.match(r'\d+', e)
    if m is not None:
        result.append(e)

print result
# ['14147618', '6137776', '5943229', '2066613']
```

**Note:** This can also be written as list comprehension:

```
print [e for e in a if re.match(r'\d+', e)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
>>> l = ['14147618', '(100%)', '6137776', '(43%)', '5943229', '(42%)', '2066613', '(14%)', 'TOTAL']
>>> [el for el in l if re.match(r'\d+$', el)]
['14147618', '6137776', '5943229', '2066613']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use re module:

```
>>> import re
>>> [item for item in s if re.match(r'\d+',item)]
['14147618', '6137776', '5943229', '2066613']
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `re` module at all , you can use `filter`over `list`.

Try this ,

```
>>> a=['14147618', '(100%)', '6137776', '(43%)', '5943229', '(42%)', '2066613', '(14%)', 'TOTAL']
>>> filter(str.isdigit, a)
['14147618', '6137776', '5943229', '2066613']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want the even-indexed elements except for the last one:

```
print [data[i] for i in range(0,len(data)-1,2)]
```